# simple match query taking ages

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple query

```
MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION*]<-(m:TYPE) RETURN m
```

and when executing the query "manually" (i.e. using the browser interface to follow edges) I only get a single node as a result as there are no further connections. Checking this with the query

```
MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION]<-(m:TYPE)<-[n:CONNECTION]-(o:TYPE) RETURN m,o
```

shows no results and

```
MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION]<-(m:TYPE) RETURN m
```

shows a single node so I have made no mistake doing the query manually.

However, the issue is that the first question takes ages to finish and I do not understand why.

*Consequently*: **What is the reason such trivial query takes so long even though the maximum result would be one?**

*Bonus*: **How to fix this issue?**

Answer (score 2):

As Tezra mentioned, the variable-length pattern match isn't in the same category as the other two queries you listed because there's no restrictions given on any of the nodes in between `n` and `m`, they can be of any type. Given that your query is taking a long time, you likely have a fairly dense graph of :CONNECTION relationships between nodes of different types.

If you want to make sure all nodes in your path are of the same label, you need to add that yourself:

```
MATCH path = (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION*]-(m:TYPE) 
WHERE all(node in nodes(path) WHERE node:TYPE)
RETURN m
```

Alternately you can use APOC Procedures, which has a fairly efficient means of finding connected nodes (and restricting nodes in the path by label):

```
MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n, {labelFilter:'TYPE', relationshipFilter:'<CONNECTION'}) YIELD node
RETURN node
SKIP 1 // to avoid returning `n`
```

Comment: I would suggest that you reword your answer to use "label" instead of "type".

Comment: Good catch, I think the 'TYPE' label through me off

Answer (score 1):

`MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION]<-(m:TYPE)<-[n:CONNECTION]-(o:TYPE) RETURN m,o` Is not a fair test of `MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION*]<-(m:TYPE) RETURN m` because it excludes the possibility of `MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION]<-(m:ANYTHING_ELSE)<-[n:CONNECTION]-(o:TYPE) RETURN m,o`.

For your main query, you should be returning DISTINCT results `MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION*]<-(m:TYPE) RETURN DISTINCT m`.

This is for 2 main reasons.

- Without distinct, each node needs to be returned the number of times for each possible path to it.
- Because of the previous point, that is a lot of extra work for no additional meaningful information.

If you use RETURN DISTINCT, it gives the cypher planner the choice to do a pruning search instead of an exhaustive search.

You can also limit the depth of the exhaustive search using `..#` so that it doesn't kill your query if you run against a much older version of Neo4j where the Cypher Planner hasn't learned pruning search yet. Example use `MATCH (n:TYPE {id:123})<-[:CONNECTION*..10]<-(m:TYPE) RETURN m`